# How do I clear a serial screen?

Tags: c++, embedded, mbed

I'm working with a mbed NXP LPC1768, and Tera Term. I having problems clearing the screen so it'll just look the stats are constantly updating without the scrolling.

Comment: I'm working with C++.

Comment: Try sending ESC "\[2J". [VT100 ESC sequences](http://www.comptechdoc.org/os/linux/howlinuxworks/linux_hlvt100.html)

Comment: Aw man, that sound much simpler than the "See if you can use a curses library." I was going to suggest.

Comment: google dec vt100 then look for the commands

Comment: The question marked as a duplicate is not a duplicate - the question is not the same, this is about clearing the screen in a terminal emulator, the other question was about clearing a console window in Windows.  Even if the answer happens to be the same for different reasons.

Answer (score 3):

TeraTerm supports emulations of DEC VT100 to DEC VT382. VT100 being the lowest common denominator (also known as ANSI Terminal).  To control VT100/ANSI terminal you send [escape sequences](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm).

The escape sequence for "erase screen" is `<ESC>[2J`.  Where `<ESC>` is the ASCII escape character `0x1b`.  So you send the *escaped* string `"\x1b[2J"` to the serial port to clear the terminal.

There is however a simpler and more efficient method of updating a value statically on the screen without clearing the entire screen. If you configure the terminal so that it requires CR+LF for newline, and then simply send only a CR as follows (for example):

```
for(;;)
{
    output( result_string ) ;
    output( "              " ) ; // enough space to overwrite the
                                 // previous result if the line 
                                 // length is variable.
    output( "\r" ) ;
    delay( update_delay) ;
}
```

Then `result_string` will be repeatedly written on the same line without scrolling or advancing.